Undesired mail by an Italian.SE visitor
I, and at least one friend as well, have received an email by someone claiming to be a software engineer from Eastern Europe who saw our contributes on italian.SE («I just discovered the italian.stackexchange forum, and I really appreciate you for the time and the feedback you're providing to the community») and asking for an opinion about and corrections on a letter he intends to send in Italian.
Is anyone else being “spammed” by this person?

Did they send the email to the one associated with your SE account? That email is visible only to employees and moderators, unless it's searchable somewhere else on the internet.

@abbyhairboat: In my case it was the same address, but it should not terribly hard to find it elsewhere. In my friend's case, it was a different address. So, at least, it should not be an employee or administrator.

I am the other person who received the email. In my case it was not sent to the address I use for SE, but to my work address (actually I think it is the one you may find googling my name-and-surname). Therefore SE is not affected at all; DaG and me however thought it would have been advisable to warn other users.

If you don't want to be contacted by email you should avoid to expose it.
Yours is currently easily accessible through your website (I remind you that your website is linked in your SE profile, and it is public). They probably just clicked on "show my full profile" reaching this page, where your email can be found.
Either hide it from your blog contacts or avoid linking your blog from your About page.

The same is true for mau's account. Following the link to his website through the About page is trivial to retrieve his email (in this case he's exposing even his home address...)

I was not contacted at the address indicated in the About page, actually ;-)
